# Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc/sql__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc/sql.clj on classpath

Tags: jdbc, clojure, compojure

I'm having issues running a simple Clojure/Compojure project using MySQL.

This is my project definition:

```
(defproject picenum "compojure"
  :description "Ascoli ❤ Clojure"
  :url "http://localhost:3000/"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [korma "0.4.2"]
                 [log4j "1.2.17"]
                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.37"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]
                 [c3p0/c3p0 "0.9.1.2"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :ring {:handler picenum.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

When I run it I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc/sql__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc/sql.clj on classpath.
```

It stopped working after I upgraded most of the dependencies.
What am I missing?

EDIT:
Here's the handler namespace definition

```
(ns picenum.handler
  (:import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource)
  (:use compojure.core
        ring.middleware.json
        ring.util.response
        korma.db
        korma.core
        hiccup.core
        hiccup.util
        hiccup.page)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql]))
```

Comment: The `project.clj` looks to be correct. Would you mind posting your namespace definition (the one in which you try to use JDBC)?

Answer (score 0):

there is not `sql.clj` on `java.jdbc` library,
please delete `[clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql]` on your file.

Comment: And what about this http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.clojure%7Cjava.jdbc%7C0.4.2%7Cjar

Comment: yes, my mistake, I just check out on java.jdbc project.clj.

Comment: I did what you suggested and now I get `No such var: jdbc/with-connection`

Comment: `Unable to resolve symbol: with-connection in this context`

Answer (score 0):

As number23_cn suggests, removing the `[clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql]` :require stops giving errors about non-existant `sql.clj`

[clojure-doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/) provides clear [information how to use the sql connector](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html).

### steps to get a working mysql connection in clojure:

add dependencies inside project.clj:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]
               [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.38"]]
```

require database connector inside namespace definition:

```
(:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as j])
```

define database connection:

```
(def db-map {:subprotocol "mysql"
             :subname "//localhost:3306/SCHEME"
             :user "DB_USER"
             :password "DB_USER_PASS"})
```

query the database:

```
(j/query db-map ["SELECT * FROM table"])
```

find more examples at
http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html